# IMPORTXML Error on Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xpath, google-sheets, xml-import

I want to import the following [table](https://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/) onto Google Sheets and schedule it to refresh once a week. I am just starting messing around with XPath, and was able to find that I will need to have the Relative XPath in the IMPORTXML formula for this to work. I used the 'XPath Helper' Chrome addon to find the same, but I am getting the "Could not fetch URL" error.

```
=IMPORTXML("www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/", "/html[@class='no-js']/body/div[@class='dvz-content'][1]/section[@class='container-width']/div[@class='table-chart']/div[@class='table-row'][1]/div[@class='table-cell t-name']/a")
```

Any help is appreciated to get me started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things - one is that the URL your requesting is missing the `http://` protocol, which is required in order for importxml to work - second here is an xpath that works (the one you were using wasnt working) and this one is much simpler -

Here is the full formula:

`=IMPORTXML("http://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/", "//*[@class='table-row']")`

[image]